# Approach for refreshing a copy database

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a copy database that has one table.  It needs to be refreshed each night.  There are three approaches:

1. Use a VB6 recordset or .NET datareader to loop through all the records in the table.  Make the appropriate changes.
2. Use SSIS to truncate the data in the table and then refresh it
3. Use a checksum to establish what records have changed then refresh that data using SSIS
4. Use a checksum to establish what records have changed then refresh that data using a recordset or datareader

The problem with approach one is that it is too slow.  It takes about two weeks to run as there are 90,000,000 records.  Approach four is too slow as well.  There are about 20,000 updates per day.

Therefore I believe it is between option two and option three.  Option two only takes about fifteen minutes.  However, users could be searching the table whilst it is being truncated and refreshed.

I am wondering if I can use transactions to isolate the work.  However, if I use a serialised transaction whilst the data is being refreshed then the table is locked for fifteen minutes.  Is there another option?

Comment: You could do [Log Shipping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103(v=sql.120).aspx) But you haven't explained why you want to do this.

Comment: You'd likely want hashbytes with an MD5 or SHA1 hash over using the checksum function. The opportunity for collisions is just too great

Comment: You could use SQL Server change tracking or Change Data Capture

Answer (score 0):

What about a stored procedure that gets kicked off with a SQL job?  It would probably work similarly to #1 but be faster.  Re-indexing before doing your update would probably help too.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely option 3. Truncating 90 mil. rows to refresh 20,000 is (as I'm sure you know) very inefficient and will just fill up your transaction logs unnecessarily.

SSIS has full transaction handling support, so should easily be able to meet your needs.

Here is a good article on using transactions with SSIS: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1585/how-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/